# Can I make a Telegram Bot only talk in an specific topic?

Tags: telegram-messenger

Telegram recently introduced [Topics](https://telegram.org/blog/topics-in-groups-collectible-usernames/it?setln=en), and I'm wondering if I can make a bot only talk in certain Topics, that would allow me to fold several Telegram groups that have different bots and needs into one group with several topics, and each topic would have it's own active bots.

As far as I can tell, there's not a way to do this and searching on the internet for this only really brings list of "TOP 10 BOTS 2022" or bot development stuff, which is not useful to me.

My guess after reading some of these results is that bot developers have to modify their code to allow Topic support, but again, I'm not really sure. I'd appreciate any tips if there's a way to achieve this. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this topic [Telegram Bot - Use Case - How to Create a Bot on Telegram and Teach It to Respond to Specific Terms](https://creativeminds.helpscoutdocs.com/article/2828-telegram-bot-use-case-how-to-create-a-bot-on-telegram-and-teach-it-to-respond-to-specific-terms)